# Matching phrases (word-search), noting finding in different columns

Tags: r

I'm working with: feedback from teachers, multiple selections from a google form. All selections end up producing a single column.

There was also the option to type in responses... so some words/responses are only present one time. There are about 50 responses, with between 1, and 7 words(ish) per entry. For the MRE I've included 5 as a vector.

```
 eg_responses <- c("Difficult, Challenging, Fair", "Necessary, Useful", "Cruel", "Easy, Challenging", "School's shouldn't have to do that")



 words_example <- c("Difficult","Easy","Fair","Challenging","Necessary","Useful")
```

While I can get a summary of the results, I need to create isolated responses so that I can select and compare with other variables later on...

What I would like to be able to do:
have columns representative of each word, and an extra column with other comments.
Look through each row for each word that was in the drop down.
while there are rows left to check look through word x.
if word is present mark in x column.
if word is not present mark NA in x column.
next column and next word when rows run out.
any other words/phrases left at the end go in the last column,
if no other words phrases are left mark end column with NA.

I'm sure I've been overcomplicating things. But I'm an absolute beginner. I'm working in R.

I have tried, separating the words, turning things into factors, then turning to character... Searching for exact complete phrases, or searching through words, would be really helpful.
There are 6 other sections with the same problem, and other sections of other variables.

I would like to have something like this at the end...
(apologies, just going to make it up bit of a chicken and egg)

```
respcolnames <- c( "Challenging", "Fair", "Unfair", "Other" )
 row1 <- c("NA", "Fair", "NA", "NA")
 row2 <- c("Challenging", "NA", "Unfair", "NA")
 row3 <- c("NA", "NA","NA", "School's shouldn't have to do that")
 teacher_responses <- cbind(row1, row2,row3)
 names(teacher_responses) <- respcolnames
```

so that the corresponding response is in the correct column. I can then strip away the "Other" responses for a more social science analysis, and use the drop down response selections for some graphics.

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the example shared?

Comment: Please clarify what a "response" is. The MRE makes it seem like a "response" is a comma-separated list of the words selected from the drop-down plus any free-response entries; but then you say you need to "create isolated responses so that I can select and compare with other variables".

Comment: Also, how do you want the data to be handled if a free-response contains one of the "words", e.g. "The program would be difficult to implement".

Comment: @RonakShah, sorry, I don't follow what you mean. I'd like a table, with the column header having the name of the option in the dropdown, or "Other comment" column, and binary yes or NA in the rows for that individual participant. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Josh, you have a good point regarding free response containing drop down words. At the moment it looks like I might be lucky and not have to worry about that! ;)